# having problems with sum() method

Tags: java, class, methods, sum

The question asks me to make a class where there are `addNumber(int numbers)` and `sum()` methods in `NumberStatistics` class. The `addNumber` method can't store any value.

```
public class NumberStatistics {

    private int number;
    private int sum;

    public NumberStatistics() {
        this.sum = 0;
    }

    public void addNumber(int numbers) {
        this.number = numbers;
        sum();            
    }

    public int sum() {
        this.sum = this.sum + this.number;
        return this.sum-this.number;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberStatistics stats = new NumberStatistics();
        stats.addNumber(3);
        stats.addNumber(5);
        stats.addNumber(1);
        stats.addNumber(2);
        System.out.println("sum: " + stats.sum());
    }
}
```

So I have to do `return this.sum-this.number;` But is there other way to achieve same result?

update: edited to fix errors.

Comment: suppose you need a integer array to store the numbers you add. and what is the purpose `amountOfNumbers`

Comment: @RajithPemabandu sorry for including the `amountOfNumbers`.It is for another part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this implementation:

```
public class NumberStatistics {
    private int sum;

    public NumberStatistics() {
        this.sum = 0;
    }

    public void addNumber(int number) {
        this.sum += number;           
    }

    public int getSum() {
        return this.sum;
    }
}
```

While this is far from an ideal implementation for a basic calculator, it meets the requirement `The addNumber method can't store any value.`  If we cannot store any state about the numbers being input, then the only option is to compute the sum on the fly.  Hence, I also renamed the `sum()` method to `getSum()`, because now it simply returns the sum which is already known.

Comment: I am confused about not storing and not storing the value. Can you give an example of storing a value? 
Like instead of `this.sum` if we use `sum` then would it store the value?

Comment: Update your question with your real requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the line:

```
this.sum = this.sum + numbers;
```

in the addNumber method, so you remove the need for the "number" variable, and in the sum method just return this.sum